# Unable to run browserstack-cypress

Tags: cypress, browserstack

I'm trying to run `browserstack-cypress-cli`:
`browserstack-cypress run --sync`

I'm constantly receiving:

```
[3/15/2021, 4:34:03 PM] - info: Reading config from C:\test\browserstack.json
[3/15/2021, 4:34:03 PM] - info: Validating the config
[3/15/2021, 4:34:03 PM] - info: Creating tests.zip with files in .
[3/15/2021, 4:34:04 PM] - info: Uploading the tests to BrowserStack
[3/15/2021, 4:34:04 PM] - error:
{
  message: 'Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established',
  stack: 'Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established\n' +
    '    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:604:14)\n' +
    '    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1513:19)\n' +
    '    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:28)\n' +
    '    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:323:22)\n' +
    '    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  path: null,
  host: 'api-cloud.browserstack.com',
  port: 443,
  localAddress: undefined
}
[3/15/2021, 4:34:04 PM] - error: Zip Upload failed.
[3/15/2021, 4:34:04 PM] - info: Deleted tests.zip successfully.
```

[Here](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress) you can find guide I have followed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you switch to a different network and execute the same command?

Seems like a network issue to me. Possibly a Proxy on your network with SSL inspection could be the reason.

Comment: I will check and let you know. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I left you a comment here https://github.com/browserstack/browserstack-cypress-cli/issues/126#issuecomment-800306074